# Accessing nth Element of a list value for a given key: Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

`d = {key: [val1, val2, val3....], key2: [valx, valy, valz, ...], ....}`

Is it possible to get nth element of the value lists? Example: `d{key2:[2]}` would return `'valz'`.

I tried `d.get({key:[0]})` but got:

> "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"

Answer (score 5):

`d[key][0]` does the trick for me, unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: This worked; although I had to do exception handling for IndexError. For some reason i was getting Index out of Range error.  Thank you all !!

Comment: Great. Are you going to mark my answer correct? :-)

Comment: i did, but it said i have to earn 15 Reputation for my feedback to go public  :(.

Answer (score 1):

To get `valz` just use `d[key2][2]`.

Comment: This doesn't work, as dictionaries don't have order.

Comment: @ppperry Yep, it was a mistake!

Comment: How is this a question of order? `d[key2]` gets the value for `key2`, which happens to be a list; appending `[2]` will give the item in position 2 of the list.

Comment: Ahhhh :-) I see, then

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `d.get({key:[0]})` is equivanlent to d`[{key:[0]}]`, amd dictionaries are illegal keys in dictionaries. The correct solution is `d[key][0]`